# Webapi inherited controllers are ignoring Route attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to have a Controller Hierarchy assembly at webapi 2 website to handle common CRUD service operation.

I Started with an abstract webapi class like this (I removed unnecesary code and injection for simplicity):

```cs
public abstract class EntityController<T> : ApiController {

[Route("GetAll")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
{
//code
}

[Route("Add")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Add(T entity)
{
//code
}

[Route("Delete")]
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(T entity)
{
//code
}

[Route("Edit")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Edit(T entity)
{
//code
}
}
```

First, I noticed that if we have controllers in external assemblies, the routes are not resolved properly. I found this post:

https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/

and when I apply the proposed changes, the routes dont use the "route" attribute. I.E. if I have the following derived class:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/thebooks")]
public class BookController : EntityController<Book>
{
public BookController() : base()
{
}
}
```

The controller prefix is api/book instead api/thebooks and if I try to call "Add" I have the exception:

Multiple actions were found that match the request:

Add on type [...]

Edit on type [...]

Find on type [...]

How can I indicate that I will use the Route and RoutePrefix attribute on inherited Controllers?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It will be helpfull if you show us your routes configuration. Also pls show us the type that you masked with `[...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and [RoutePrefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routeprefixattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) are not inherited because [Inherited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routeprefixattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is set to false as shown below:

```
[Inherited=false)]
public class RoutePrefixAttribute : Attribute
```

You can read more about `Inherited` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_AttributeUsageAttribute_Inherited).

You will need to decorate your subclasses again unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override the inherited false of the Route and RoutePrefix with a bit of jiggery pokery.

Firstly inherit from `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` - notice the inherit `true` inside `GetCustomAttributes`

```
public class InheritanceDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>(true);
    }
}
```

Then in you application startup class (`WebApiConfig` or `Startup`) register it against your `HttpConfiguration` as an extension, then change the line in the startup from `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to `config.MapInheritedAttributeRoutes();`

```
public static class HttpConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void MapInheritedAttributeRoutes(this HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new InheritanceDirectRouteProvider());
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapInheritedAttributeRoutes();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Taken from this article https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/inheriting-route-attributes-in-asp-net-web-api/